# How to select a value of a row in a table with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the value of a row in a table with jquery, when the user click on it.

I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work correctly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


                $.post("./php/myjson.php", function(data, status) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var trHTML = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.giocatori.length; i++) {

                        trHTML += '<tr><td><img src="../media/image/squadre/' + obj.giocatori[i].Squadra.toLowerCase() + '.png"/></td><td>'+obj.giocatori[i].Giocatore+'</td><td>' + obj.giocatori[i].Cognome + '</td><td>' + obj.giocatori[i].Prezzo + '</td></tr>';
                    }
                    trHTML+='</tbody>';
                    $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

                });
                $( "#records_table tr" ).on( "click", function(  ) {
                      alert( $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
                });

            });
```

```css
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="records_table" border="1">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Squadra</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
                <th>Prezzo</th>

            </tr>

    </table>
```

Where is the error ?

Comment: Change this  `$( "#records_table tr" ).on( "click", function(  ) {`  to `$( "#records_table" ).on( "click", 'tr',  function(  ) {`

Comment: It works ! Why my code wasn't correct ?

Comment: @Alexander Make it an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the table exists when the page loads, its contents are loaded after the page loads (after `DOM ready` event). You want to use a delegated event. Therefore, try this:

```
$( "#records_table" ).on( "click", "tr", function(  ) {
    alert( $('td', this).eq(2).html() );
});
```

**NOTE**: Adding this section -- your version -- in the success call back of the the ajax call after the new content is added should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You are keeping tbody in HTML, but adding the content to table. Please change the following.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
            $.post("./php/myjson.php", function(data, status) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var trHTML = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.giocatori.length; i++) {

                    trHTML += '<tr><td><img src="../media/image/squadre/' + obj.giocatori[i].Squadra.toLowerCase() + '.png"/></td><td>'+obj.giocatori[i].Giocatore+'</td><td>' + obj.giocatori[i].Cognome + '</td><td>' + obj.giocatori[i].Prezzo + '</td></tr>';
                }
                $('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML);

            });
            $( "#records_table tr" ).on( "click", function(  ) {
                  alert( $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
            });

        });
```

as well as you can close the tbody in HTML.

Squadra
                ID
                Cognome
                Prezzo